# Model details showing in text on View - how do I stop the text showing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am working in MVC, chtml and C# and slowly making progress on the project that I am working on - however, the details of the model is showing at the top of the view as `System.Collections.Generic.List1` and cannot find why it should do so.

The Rest of the view is working fine.

How to sort this issue?

Top of the View:

```
    @Model BB2020MVC.Models.RaceNames;


<div><h2>All Races</h2></div>
```

Partial View - Navigation Bar:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Main")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Base Teams", "Index", "BaseTeams")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Rules", "Index", "BaseRules")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Rosters", "Index", "Rosters")</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the Layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    @{Html.RenderAction(actionName: "Navbar", controllerName: "Main");}
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, the model type declaration at the top of your view should start with `@model`, not `@Model`, but I can't test that at the moment.

Comment: @Collen Thanks for responding - can be either as HTML does not care about caps unless you are using strict, some people prefer Camel Case I prefer Pascal
- the issue happens with both `@Model` and `@model`

Comment: @Collen - just tested again - issue has now been resolved, you was right!  Guess I got a bit of work to do now on all my views lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was caused by using `@Model` instead of `@model` - Credit should go to **Collen** for the following quote that assisted with this question:

> If I recall correctly, the model type declaration at the top of your view should start with @model, not @Model, but I can't test that at the moment.

Upon testing further, `@Model` presents the user with the details of the model that was presented to the View by the Controller followed by the string of anything that was after the model detail.

For example, in this question, `@Model BB2020MVC.Models.RaceNames;` would present `System.Collections.Generic.List1[]BB2020MVC.Models.RaceNames;` to the user; the rest of the View would display properly as the View would pick up values from `ViewBag` and the presented Model.

`@model`, however, declares the model correctly and does not show the model details, it also allows `@Model` and `@model` to correctly display the correct model fields when you are programming the View.